# Counting the number of mismatches by field MONGODB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of entities like:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("123b1c231c4a460005dc658r"),
"unitId" : "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b",
"name" : "Main",
"shortName" : "Main",
"controlOperator" : "admin"
```

I have logins ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"] and I need to count:

```
admin : 10
noAdmin : 15
john : 0
jack : 14
```

I try

```
db
.getCollection('appeals')
.aggregate([
{$match: {$or: [{unitId: "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b", controlOperator: {$in: ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"]}}, {unitId: "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b", controlOperator: {$nin: ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"]}}]}},
{$project: {_id: 0}},
{$group: {_id: "$controlOperator", appeals: {$push: "$controlOperator"},
count: {$sum: 1}}}])
```

But I get only matched value:

```
admin : 10
noAdmin : 15
jack : 14
```

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- if you only have those 4 possible values you can do the group like bellow to include the zero count
- you can replace your group with this group

*alternative you can keep your group, and add the zero count fields if they are missing, or add them on the client with application code

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6282786f853f039c69b0f8df)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": 
   {"$or": 
     [{"$and": 
         [{"unitId": {"$eq": "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b"}},
           {"controlOperator": 
             {"$in": ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"]}}]},
       {"$and": 
         [{"unitId": {"$eq": "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b"}},
           {"controlOperator": 
             {"$in": ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"]}}]}]}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "admin": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$controlOperator", "admin"]}, 1, 0]}},
    "noAdmin": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$controlOperator", "noAdmin"]}, 1, 0]}},
    "john": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$controlOperator", "john"]}, 1, 0]}},
    "jack": 
     {"$sum": {"$cond": [{"$eq": ["$controlOperator", "jack"]}, 1, 0]}}}}])
```

Query2

- more general, for anysize of operators array
- the first match and group is like your query
- replace root to make it `operator:count`
- group by null, to merge all documents to 1
- merge with the zero values {"helen": 0, "jack": 0, "john": 0}
  (you can create this with javascript)
- replace the root with it

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6282985f853f039c69b0f8e0)

```js
// Assume this is the incoming argument:
var targetOps = ["admin", "noAdmin", "john", "jack"];

// After this point, everything is driven dynamically from targetOps.

// From list, setup the default object where count = 0:
var opsObj = {};
targetOps.forEach(function(x) {
    opsObj[x] = 0;
});


aggregate(
[{"$match": {
   "unitId": "58bd51815744bf06e001b57b"},
   "controlOperator": {"$in": targetOps}
 }},
 {"$group": {"_id": "$controlOperator", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": {"$arrayToObject": [[{"k": "$_id", "v": "$count"}]]}}},
 {"$group": 
   {"_id": null, "controlOperators": {"$mergeObjects": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     // Important that opsObj comes *first* and the calculated counts object
     // is overlaid on top of it:
     {"$mergeObjects": [opsObj, "$controlOperators"]}}}
])
```

Comment: Thank you, i'll try. But I have different login arrays with more numbers of logins. perhaps there is a more elegant solution for large login-arrays?

Comment: my opinion is that the easiest way to do it, is with javascript on the client to add the missing ones, but in case you want to do it inside mongodb you can try the Query2 also

Comment: Great use of $mergeObjects to set up defaults -- but I am not a huge fan of rvals as keys.

Comment: yeah rvals are terrible as keys, but he asked for it, in general all the query should be simple(like the query he already had), and just add those with javascript i think

Comment: But I don't understand one simple thing - how to get map with count match and mismatch String[] values in field?

Comment: if you mean this `{"helen": 0, "jack": 0, "john": 0}` you have to create it before sending the query for example with javascript and same it in a javascript variable, if the database doesnt have those names, you have to give them with zero values.

Comment: The OP is a little off: the `$or` has `$in: list` , `$nin: list` with the same `unitId` so it is effectively just `unitId`.   The answer has different lists for the initial `$match` vs. the default setup (`name:0`) object which I think is intent drift.  I am going to edit the first answer it to get it a clearer solution.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this highly condensed version of docs supplied by the OP:

```js
var r = [
    {controlOperator : "admin"},
    {controlOperator : "admin"},
    {controlOperator : "admin"},
    {controlOperator : "buzz"},
    {controlOperator : "buzz"},
    {controlOperator : "steve"}
];
```

Here is a way to get the desired output:

```js
// admin and buzz will be found.
// dave will not be found and is not in input set; result = 0
// steve is in input set but not in ops targets so will not show up at all
var ops = ['admin','buzz','dave']

c=db.foo.aggregate([
    // Perform all top level filterings here.  At a minimum we filter for
    // controlOperator but add more as needed:                                    
    {$match: {controlOperator: {$in: ops} }}

    // Let initial $group do the heavy lifting of counting                        
    ,{$group: {_id: "$controlOperator", N: {$sum:1}}}

    // OK.  Things that are not found will not make it into $group,               
    // so we have to turn the problem around and iterate over ops                 
    // to see what is NOT there.                                                  
    // Start by turning the output set into a single doc with an                  
    // array so we can exploit array functions:                                   
    ,{$group: {_id: null, M: {$push: {name: "$_id", N:"$N"}}}}

   
    // Rebuild M but from the perspective of the target ops list,                 
    // not the M array.  If we find an op name in the list, we                    
    // keep the result else we invent a new item with N = 0:                      
    ,{$project: {M: {$map: {
        input: ops,
            in: {$let: {
                vars: {ee: {$filter: {input: '$M',
                           as: 'zz',
                           cond: {$eq:['$$zz.name','$$this']}
                             }}
                      },
                in: {$cond: [
                        {$gt:[{$size:'$$ee'},0]}, // IF found                     

                        // THEN take it; only 0 or 1 items thanks to              
                        // $group.  The item is an array so take $first:          
                        {$first:'$$ee'},

                        // ELSE create a zero entry:                              
                        {name:'$$this', N:0}
                     ]}
            }}
        }}
    }}

    // At this point we have all info we need, but if you really want             
    // to break up that M array, do this.  Note that we opt for "good"            
    // key values here, i.e.                                                      
    //   {name: "admin", N:3}  // GOOD                                            
    // vs. the OP target which puts rvals into the key space:                     
    //   {"admin":3}  // Less good                                                
    ,{$unwind: '$M'}
    ,{$project: {_id:false, name: '$M.name', N:'$M.N'}}

]);
```

OPINION:  This seems like a lot of work considering the client knows the full ops list and can do this:

```js
c=db.foo.aggregate([
    {$match: {controlOperator: {$in: ops} }}
    ,{$group: {_id: "$controlOperator", N: {$sum:1}}}
]);

c.forEach(function(doc) {
    var x = ops.indexOf(doc['_id']);
    print(doc['_id'],x);
    if(x != -1) {
        print(doc);
        ops.splice(x,1); // remove from ops list...
    }
});

// What hasn't been removed is zero:
print("the following are zero:", ops);
```

Finally:  there is potentially a cool use of `$setUnion` here by taking the ops targets, changing them into a "default" set of `{op:name, N:0}` objects, and then merging the calculated results on top.  Those targets with no group will remain as `N:0`.  I cannot get `$setUnion` to work against sets of objects though, only scalars.